# Elements not aligned correctly in Chrome

Tags: css

http://www.ekeeler.com/mbti/index.html

Can anyone tell me why the elements on my page are so out of whack in Chrome? The elements seem to be aligning just fine in IE.

screenshot in chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAlEi.jpg
screenshot in IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6jtY.jpg

Comment: Provide complete example in https://jsfiddle.net/, for example, and explain what you mean by elements. It will be also useful to see screenshot that explains the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how's that page supposed to look, looks perfectly sane to me(using chromium 58 which is essentially chrome)

Comment: do you want `menu` to be on top, `leftcolumn` to be on left and `rightcolumn` to be on right ? if yes again it works with me :) , what version of chrome are you using ?

Comment: I posted a screenshot to show what I'm seeing

Comment: well that's not what I'm seeing , what version of chrome are you using ?

Comment: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: that's strange, what you call "IE version" is what I'm seeing in my chromium 58(which is again essentially chrome), hmmm

Comment: could be your extensions messing your content, try to test your webpage without any extensions

Comment: make sure that what you test is http://www.ekeeler.com/mbti/index.html not some old version of it

Comment: last but not least while I highly doubt it but worth trying, test the webpage under a linux machine(preferably a real one instead of a virtual one), I assumed that you're a windows user because you mentioned "IE" :)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. It must be an extension or something because I tried loading the page on a different computer and it shows up correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems everything good here.

[image]

Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)